# python how to write one line if statement

Tags: python

I am trying to write a one line if statement with no else.  What is the correct way to do this?  I want the statement to do nothing if the if condition is not matched.

```
PODQS1_R10 = ""
PODQS2_R11 = ""
PODQS3_R12 = ""
    
PODQS1_R10 = "4751" if row[10] == "4751"
```

Comment: You have to have an `else` in a conditional expression. What is it supposed to assign when the condition is false?

Comment: @Barmar do nothing

Comment: Then you can't use a conditional expression. The expression always has a value.

Comment: @bakalolo Ternary statements don't work that way. You could do `if row[10] == "4751": PODQS1_R10 = "4751"` in a single line for a regular `if` statement

Comment: `else None` is almost certainly what you want.  PODQ51_R10 MUST have a value.

Comment: @TimRoberts I already initialized it to "" earlier

Comment: You could use `else PODQS1_R10` to keep the same value.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a one-liner?

Comment: The short answer is, it's not possible.  The best you can do is either `PODQS1_R10 = '4751' if row[10] == '4751' else ''` or `if row[10] == '4751': PODS1_R10 = '4751'`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use else, there is no other way when using one line `if.. else` statement. But, it looks really similar and I think it shouldn't be a problem.

One line `if.. else` statement schema:

```py
variable = value_if_condition_true if condition else value_if_condition_false
```

In your case:

```py
PODQS1_R10 = "4751" if row[10] == "4751" else None
```

[without `else`]
The only way to keep away from using `else` is classic `if.. else` statement without any action in the opposite case:

```py
if row[10] == "4751":
    PODQS1_R10 = "4751"
```

The compilator will just skip creating `PODQS1_R10`.

[TIP]
Try to avoid using one line `if.. else` statements because code loses its clarity.

[TIP 2]
Following PEP8, dont't use UPPER CASE as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna state this as a formal answer.

If your code has:

- Obscure-looking variable names with no real rhyme or reason to a new maintainer, and
- tough-to-spot at a first glance requirements as to why a value should be something,

then the *last* thing you should do is put the `if` statement on one line.

You don't have to have an `else` statement with an `if` statement anyway.

```
if row[10] == "4751":
    PODQS1_R10 = "4751"
```

There may even be an opportunity to streamline that a little by assigning it the contents of the list if you know that they're equal anyway.

```
if row[10] == "4751":
    PODQS1_R10 = row[10]
```